# Where to store sensitive information in a Drupal Module?

Tags: php, security, drupal, drupal-7

In a module I'm creating I have some sensitive information I need to store securely: A remote database host, username, and password.

It seems that the only storage available is in the Drupal database, which worries me since this means if Drupal is compromised so is this other database. The `settings.php` file in `sites/all/default` was my second option, but I'm having trouble writing to it. Various `chmod` commands in FTP and SSH to 777 and 666 won't open the file to writing. I'm also not sure if the variables I set there are available anywhere else.

Are there any other ways to store this information securely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track using settings.php. You can [use the $conf variable in settings.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--globals.php/global/conf/6) to set variables that you can access in modules using [variable_get](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/6).

Comment: A related question: Why can't I write to `settings.php`? Its permissions are at 777 in FTP and SSH but I can't edit the file in FTP. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: `Command: STOR settings.php` - `Response: 553 Rename/move failure: Permission denied`. And let me clarify that I can edit in SSH, just not in FTP

Comment: Are you maybe editing from a different account within ssh (using su or something) than what you're using to FTP?

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm... this seems like something you shouldn't do in general.  Write an API that sits at the remote database that you can access.

If however you insist on direct database access.  Hard code the host, username and password in a file, put the file outside your document root and include it from there.  For example, if your document root (i.e. where Drupal's index.php file is) was /www/htdocs, put a file containing the info at something like /www/secure and include it where you need it.  Then if php stops working for some reason, the file isn't in a readable location to the outside world but PHP can include it within the site as necessary.

Sure somebody might see that you were including the file but they wouldn't be able to see the file itself unless they hacked your server (rather than just Drupal) and in that situation, your pretty much screwed anyway.

Comment: drupal keeps the contents of the settings.php file secure, and putting this outside the document root has it's own security problems.

Comment: @mirzu Drupal only keeps it secure as long as PHP doesn't fail.  No file containing sensitive information like logins or passwords should be inside your document root.  Especially not for a remote server.  At least if the MySQL instance is local you can set it to only accept incoming commections from localhost. (I don't think this suggestion warranted a vote down...)

Comment: If file permissions are set correctly even without PHP the settings.php file should not be accessible via http. If a user has local access there is no advantage to having the file out of the web-root. Allowing the remote database to only accept connections from this server is a good security step, and should be taken regardless of how the connection credentials are stored.

Comment: @mirzu I would genuinely be interested to know what file permissions would, if you had apache running but not PHP, stop a person reading a file within your doc root if they navigated to it but when you enabled PHP, would allow PHP to access the file.  Wouldn't the user reading the file in both cases be apache?

Comment: My apologies, you are correct in that if php is down there is nothing stopping the file from being read. To test this locally: I had make quite a few changes to my http.conf file to even get apache running without php. Now I'm curious, under which surcomstances, becides modifying the http.conf would you have a situation were apache is left running and php "goes down"?

Comment: @mirzu I can't come up with a situation that you can effect off the top of my head but I have seen it happen.  I've been discussing this particular question with my colleagues and they agree that it is unlikely to be a problem but that it is much safer to put the file outside your document root.  Denying access to the file in an htaccess was also suggested but that was universally agreed to be an ugly solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using a config file is ideal for this type of information.   However doing a chmod 777 or 666 is a **really bad** idea.  The problem is that both of these settings allow the file GLOBALLY read/write.  So if you are on a shared host,  then its possible for another user on the system to access your file.   On install trying using php's chmod() function to do a chmod 500 on the file.  (500 should work in most cases,  the most important part is that the last number is zero).

Comment: That was only for testing. However even with that hugely open permission, I can't write to the file over FTP. Do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: @TheLQ If you can't write to a chmod 777 file over FTP then its not a problem with the file permissions.  Further more using FTP is a **very serious** vulnerability.  You should be using SFTP or FTPS.

Comment: So then whats the problem? I can write to every single file besides this one, which Drupal has somehow locked. And I am using FTPES. But I normally don't specify that every single time

Comment: @TheLQ if the file is open for writing then you won't be able to overwrite it.  To be honest there could be another problem,  ask serverfault.